# iOS Game Center error: status = 5008, missing required header key: x-gk-bundle-version

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit, game-center-leaderboard

I had just updated xcode and my device to 8.4. The game center would through the 5008 error saying it failed to authenticate but on the device screen it would authenticate normally. However the leaderboard was empty and for a moment I thought Game Center server was down or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to delete GameKit.framework (remove reference) from the project and add it back again. I lost 2 days figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

I just received a bug report from a user with this exact error. No other users have any problems. He's running an `iPhone 5` with `iOS 9.0.2`. Many other users are using this same iOS version, and I re-added the GameKit SDK just before releasing the game, so I don't think this fix is the problem in my case. If anybody has any other suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was device specific – in Settings on the device, turn off Game Center and then turn it back on and log in if necessary. No further 5008 or other authentication errors.